# C# Entering string into external process console

Tags: process, pipe, external

I am trying to find a way to input strings into a console of an external program that is already running on my pc of which I have no control over the code.
But I simply have no clue where to look for something like this.
I've looked into pipes as someone told me he used them for a similar purpose to mine but for all I can find they don't really make sense for what I'm trying, but I might be wrong.
I would like to have a way that can run fully in the background, so it's not simply a bot that types manually.

What would be a good/simple method of doing what I'm trying?

Comment: Did you try anything for this?

Comment: Well I've tried a few things but it's very hard to get it right when you don't know if you're on the right track. I'm simply not experienced enough with this to know what kind of method I'd use for accomplishing what I'm looking for. I've been putting time into this for a few days now but can't find anything that is confirmed good for this. That's really what I'd like to know, what would work and then I can invest time into understanding that.